# To prove $6|σ(6n-1) , ∀n∈ \mathbb N$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, divisor-sum

Let $σ(n)$ denote the sum of all the positive divisors of $n∈ \mathbb N$. I think that $6$ divides $σ(6n-1)$ for all  $n∈ \mathbb N$ , but I am not able to prove it. So, a proof of the result (if it is true and I think it is) will be much appreciated.

Comment: Prove that $de=6n-1$ then of the two numbers $d,e$, one is of the form $6k+1$, the other, $6r-1$.

Comment: @ Gerry Myerson: That I do know , but the problem is in the canonical factorization of $n$ we get primes with powers.

Comment: Huh? Who said anything about primes?

Comment: Also prove that no such number can be a square number too.

Answer (score 3):

If $n=6k-1$ then $n$ is not square. (You can easily check this fact.) So if $d\mid n$ then $d\neq n/d$. Furthermore, we get $(d,2)=(d,3)=1$. That is, $d\equiv\pm1 \pmod 6$ so we get
$$
d+\frac{n}{d}=d+\frac{6k-1}{d}\equiv d-\frac{1}{d} \equiv 0 \pmod 6.
$$

Therefore $6\mid d+n/d$ for all $d\mid n$. Since $n$ is not square,
$$
\sigma(n)=\sum_{d\mid n,\,d<\sqrt{n}}d+\frac{n}{d}\equiv 0\pmod 6.
$$

Answer (score 1):

The sum of divisors is weakly multiplicative, which means that if $\operatorname{gcd}(a,b)=1$, then $\sigma(ab) = \sigma(a)\sigma(b)$.  This allows to divide it into its prime-power divisors, eg $\sigma(2^a 3^b \dots) = \sigma(2^a)\sigma(3^b)\dots$.

A number of the form of $6n-1$ must have at least one prime as a divisor of this form, suppose this is $p$.  It is easy to show that there must be an odd count of primes of this form, since $5^{2m}=1 \pmod 6$  So we pick one that has an odd power.

We just need to show that if $p^m = 5 \pmod 6$, then the sum of its divisors is a multiple of $6$.  Since $p^{2m}=1 \pmod{6}$, it follows that at least one m for the p must be odd.

Accordingly, the sum of divisors of a power of $p$ is $1+p+p^2+p^3+\dots$  When $m$ is odd, we can divide it into $(1+p)(1+p^2+p^4+\dots)$, and the first divisor is a multiple of $6$.

Therefore the whole number must be a multiple of 6.

Aside:

The weakly multiplicative manner of $\sigma()$ is how one finds multiplicatively perfect numbers, for example.  $\sigma(120) = \sigma(8) \sigma(3) \sigma(5) = 15\cdot 4 \cdot 6 = 360 = 3\times 120$.  It's just about adding factors to the LHS and crossing out what's left.

Comment: 1. You use $n$ with two different meanings. 2. 5 is a prime divisor of 275 of the form $6n-1$, but the power of 5 dividing 275 is an even one.

Comment: The number 275 is $5^2\cdot 11$, and the power on 11 is odd.  In any case, $77$ consist of factors of this type, the first will fail the mod 6 rule too.

Comment: OK, what you have now looks right. But I think it's the hard way.

Comment: I used this exact technique to find multiply perfect numbers of various forms and factors.  It's about the easiest way, because you can prove that weakly multiplicative nature, and then it's a matter of finding factors of 5, mod 6.  An odd number of 5's is called for.

Comment: I don't think it's the easiest way to do this problem. Did you see my comment on the question?

Comment: You could have a number like $1625 = 5^3 \cdot 13$, where the only factor of the form $p=5 \pmod{6}$ is a power.  That's why you have to allow for powers as well.  @GerryMyerson  Yes, i saw your comment, but you don't handle powers in that case.

Comment: What do powers have to do with anything? If $de=6n-1$, then one of the two numbers $d,e$ is 1 mod 6, and the other is 5 mod 6, so $d+e$ is a multiple of 6. The end.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10911/discussion-between-wendy-krieger-and-gerry-myerson)

Comment: Sorry, I don't do chat.